# How to understand this matrix math

Tags: c#, matrix, xna

I am following a tutorial trying to learn about game development. It is on a part for collision detection. I understand what it does, but not how it does it. I want to be able to understand what is happening. Can someone explain it?

```
Matrix matrix1To2 = matrix1 * Matrix.Invert(matrix2);
Vector2 pos1 = new Vector2(x1, y1);
Vector2 pos2 = Vector2.Transform(pos1, mat1To2);
```

The tutorial says this is to find where the image intersects at based on an x/y value of the first image. I have a basic understanding of what a matrix is and such, but not how this works.

Comment: This is just applying a matrix transform to a vector.  That's all we can tell you from this code.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, and likely for all stackexchange sites. If you are into game development you have to understand basic matrix/vector math (which is a topic that can not to be satisfactory covered in half-page SO replay).

Comment: I am not asking for a full in depth tutorial. Just a basic overview of what is happening. Like multiplying the first matrix by the inverse of the second does this. Transforming that point by the multiplied matrix does this.

Comment: @Emrys90: That **is** asking for a tutorial.  If you need an understanding of what matrix multiplication does, then the place to go is a decent maths textbook.  Or even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

Comment: I don't think it is asking for that much. Just a vague answer of what happens. I understand how to multiply matrices together. Just not how this example works.

Comment: @Emrys90: There's nothing we can tell you about this example other than what the code literally already says.  Because we have no idea what `matrix1` and `matrix2` represent, nor `pos2`.

Comment: All I am asking for is to explain what is happening. Is the x and y coordinate of the first image having a transformation done to it that the second image originally went through?

Comment: There are no images in that code, so it's impossible to say.  If you provide more context (i.e. what the inputs and outputs to this code are), then there's a small chance that someone could help you...

Comment: There are two images, and it is checking to see if they overlap each other for collision detection.

Comment: Ok, so what are `matrix1`, `matrix2`, `pos2`?

Comment: Matrix 1 and 2 are the matrices of transformations the images went through to get to their current screen coordinates. Position one is a loop through the image width and height. Position two is the coordinates of the second image that overlaps position 1.

Comment: Oh, then it's simple.  This is presumably just a transform from Image1 coordinate space to Image2 coordinate space.  i.e. given pixel (x1,y1) in Image1, what pixel in Image2 does that correspond to?

Comment: Yeah. I get that part. I am just confused on how it gets to that point. Like what happens that transforms it to that image 2 coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A practically identical question is asked and answered here: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/79167/479452.aspx

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Could you answer one more question? There's one thing left I do not understand. It was my understanding that the matrices store the transformations done to the original image. Would it not make more sense then that transforming a vector by that matrix would transform it to a local coordinate, and not a world space coordinate?

Comment: It would depend on what coordinate space the input vector is in. For example, if a particular matrix were to apply a translate transformation, then it would transform a local vector into a translated local vector, and a world space vector into a translated world space vector. If you know that the matrix you are using represents the required transformation to get from local space to world space then you know that an input vector in local space will result in an output vector in world space.

Comment: I only kind of understand what you are saying. Sorry for my ignorance. I have never really done this kind of math before. All I know is the matrix contains the transformations that the image goes through to get to its position on the screen. Translate, Scale, Rotate.

Comment: A matrix is a mathematical construct that can describe any transformation - not just that specific case to do with images.

Comment: I used the wrong terminology above. Either replace the word 'vector' for the word 'point', or 'translate' for 'scale'. A vector represents a difference between two points and is thus not modified by a translation.